# JS RegEx for all file links except PDFs

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match all href attributes in a HTML document that contain links to a specific folder, that aren't PDFs. I'm having trouble getting it to match, I have one that gets all PDFs:

```
var regexPDF = new RegExp('href=[\'|"](assets/.*?\.pdf)?[\'|"]','gi');
```

But my attempts to exclude PDFs haven't got me very far. Is there a way to do what I'm after, or am I better just matching all files then using a conditional statement to check if it's a PDF? Ta!

Darren

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use a negative lookahead `(?!..)` before the last 4 characters:

```
var regexPDF = new RegExp('href=[\'"](assets/(?:.*?(?!\.pdf).{4}|.{0,3}))?[\'"]','gi');
```

Notice: you don't need to use `|` in a character class, since it is seen as literal

Answer (score 0):

Negative patterns are something regex isn't too good at. However you could do something like the following:

```
var regexPDF = /[^.]*?\.(?!pdf)/gi;

// examples
"test.exe".match(regexPDF) // returns "test."
"test.pdf".match(regexPDF) // returns null
```

This has the disadvantage that is does not display the type of the file (in case you need the result) but is DOES filter all pdfs out. It also will break on dots in the filename like `test.pdf.bak` (but you could enhance the regex to recognize this if needed).

sidenote: Don't use the Regex Constructor but rather the plain regex literal notation `/.../`.

Comment: No I need to get the result. Why don't use the constructor?

Comment: @dazhall using constructors is generally not advised in javascript (for regex,objects,arrays,strings). You can just get the full href after you filtered out the pdfs. You don't need to work on the returnvalue directly so I think it does not matter that the regex won't return the type.